# How to restore the default show/close animations for a window when setting WindowStyle in WindowLoaded?

Tags: wpf, winapi

I'm trying to create a window using C# and WPF with the following XAML properties:

```
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
```

Setting these values removes all of the standard window functionality, but I can get most of it back using the WindowChrome class
as follows:

```
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="25" ResizeBorderThickness="7" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Next, I create my own buttons to replace the ones that no longer exist in the title bar and set their behavior:

```
    private void minimizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(this);
    }

    private void closeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.CloseWindow(this);
    }

    private void MaximizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
        {
            SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(this);
        }
        else
        {
            SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(this);
        }
    }
```

This works, but because I've set the WindowStyle to none, all of the native Window animations are missing. At minimum these include:

1. The fade in effect when the window is first displayed.
2. The Minimize effect (when minimizing the window from the buttons or task bar).
3. The Maximize/Restore animations.
4. The Close animation when closing the window.

Thanks to the help of reddit user draxus99, I was able to restore the minimize and maximize/restore animations (number 2 and 3 in the list above) using the WindowsAPI as follows:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

    public IntPtr myHWND;
    public const int GWL_STYLE = -16;

    public static class WS
    {
        public static readonly long
        WS_BORDER = 0x00800000L,
        WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000L,
        WS_CHILD = 0x40000000L,
        WS_CHILDWINDOW = 0x40000000L,
        WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x02000000L,
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS = 0x04000000L,
        WS_DISABLED = 0x08000000L,
        WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000L,
        WS_GROUP = 0x00020000L,
        WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000L,
        WS_ICONIC = 0x20000000L,
        WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x01000000L,
        WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000L,
        WS_MINIMIZE = 0x20000000L,
        WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000L,
        WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000L,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
        WS_POPUP = 0x80000000L,
        WS_POPUPWINDOW = WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU,
        WS_SIZEBOX = 0x00040000L,
        WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000L,
        WS_TABSTOP = 0x00010000L,
        WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000L,
        WS_TILED = 0x00000000L,
        WS_TILEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
        WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000L,
        WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000L;
    }

    public static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        {
            return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
        }
        else
        {
            return new IntPtr(SetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong.ToInt32()));
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myHWND = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        IntPtr myStyle = new IntPtr(WS.WS_CAPTION | WS.WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS.WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS.WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS.WS_SYSMENU | WS.WS_SIZEBOX);
        SetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(null, myHWND), GWL_STYLE, myStyle);
    }
```

The problem is that the fade in animation that is normally displayed when a window first opens and the fade out animation when a window is closed are both missing, so the window simply pops in and out of existence when opening or closing the program instead of showing the normal fade transition. I suspect that the missing close animation may be due to the fact that I'm binding the close button click action to:

```
    SystemCommands.CloseWindow(this);
```

Which may be closing the window before the animation has a chance to display, but I have no idea why the initial fade in animation is not showing unless I need to set the window style even earlier than in the Window_Loaded event.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to make a WPF window where I can draw in the non-client area that also supports transparency. I can do this using the method described in my post, but with the issue of the missing animations (due to borderstyle = none). If I change the window style in the Window_Loaded event, the min/max/restore animations work perfectly, but the fade in and fade out on opening/closing the form are missing.

Comment: Something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745861.aspx)?

Comment: The effect I want is kind of similar, but I don't know if the solution in that link would work for my case since I need to use the WindowChrome class to extend the nonclient area into the window (or DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea if I were using a different language that doesn't have the WindowChrome class).

Comment: Here's a video that demonstrates what I mean better than I could ever explain it. I first show the code, then the program running with an animations demo, but notice when the form is first opened or closed, it simply pops in and out of existence rather than fading in. At the end of the video I close an explorer window to demonstrate the subtle fade effect that the form should have.

https://youtu.be/3eDyUbmuDDk

Answer (score 1):

This answer is quite a few years late, but I was using the fix from draxus99 that you have in your question and had the same issue with the opening and closing window animations being missing until I stumbled across the cause by accident.

Turns out, having `AllowsTransparency="True"` for your window will not only remove the default border of the window (such as the rounded edges and border color for Windows 11) but it'll also get rid of the opening and closing animation that draxus99's fix was supposed to provide. By removing that line, you will get those features back. The only downside to this is that you'll miss out on anything that requires `AllowsTransparency` to be set to true, which seems to be the problem you're facing. But unless you're planning on making your own rounded corners for your window or having some transparent bits in it, you shouldn't be doing this anyway due to its detriment on performance (from what I've read).

Also, if there is any reader having trouble trying to use draxus99's fix, see this example of me using it to restore the window animations for the launcher of a project I'm a part of: https://github.com/SubnauticaNitrox/Nitrox/pull/2031/files. It was refactored to better fit the structure of this specific project by one of the other devs there, but you should be able to replicate it for your own use.

***EDIT***: There is another feature of the window that isn't restored with the above fixes, which is the application context menu (i.e. when you right click a text box to paste text). I am not sure how to restore the Windows 11 style of context menu for this. You can see the differences that I'm talking about below (Default/Unrestored style vs. Win 11 style):

[image: Unrestored context menu style]  [image: Windows 11 context menu style]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set fade in/out animations with the property `Opacity` like the this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/67368cfe-79d5-4040-968f-2a2d2bff24f3/wpf-splashscreen-with-login-form?forum=wpf) manually. something like:

```
<Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Completed="fadeCompleted" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: That would work of course, but I really want the native animations if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but this is the solution I used in our project.

For the minimize/restore animation, we're still calling `SetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)` on window's Loaded event to let system handle it, but for the close/open animation, we did it this way:

**Disclaimer: This code snippet is not production ready, use it at your own risk!**

In window's resource, declare these two storyboards, you need to add a `ScaleTransform` to window's `RenderTransform`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="WindowCloseAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
            To="0.95"
            Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
            To="0.95"
            Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            To="0"
            Duration="0:0:0.15"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="WindowOpenAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
            From="0.95"
            To="1"
            Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
            From="0.95"
            To="1"
            Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="0"
            To="1"
            Duration="0:0:0.15"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then, subscribe to window's `Loaded` and `Closing` event:

```
private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Calling SetWindowLongPtr64 to set window style here.
    IntPtr currentHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    WindowsUtilities.SetCommonWindowStyle(new HandleRef(null, currentHandle));

    // If transparency is not allowed, window open animation will be handled by system.
    if (!AllowsTransparency)
    {
        return;
    }

    Storyboard windowOpenAnimation = FindResource("WindowOpenAnimation") as Storyboard;
    if (windowOpenAnimation == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    windowOpenAnimation.Begin(this);
}

private void OnWindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // If transparency is not allowed, window close animation will be handled by system.
    if (!AllowsTransparency)
    {
        return;
    }

    // If closing animation hasn't completed yet, prevent window from closing so the animation actually plays.
    if (!_isClosingAnimationCompleted)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    Storyboard windowCloseAnimation = FindResource("WindowCloseAnimation") as Storyboard;
    if (windowCloseAnimation == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    windowCloseAnimation.Completed += OnWindowCloseAnimationCompleted;
    windowCloseAnimation.Begin(this);
}

private void OnWindowCloseAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set _isClosingAnimationCompleted to true so when Close() is called, it'll actually close the window.
    _isClosingAnimationCompleted = true;
    Close();
}
```

`_isClosingAnimationCompleted` is a private field of your Window class to indicate whether the window can be closed or not.

Please note this approach breaks the MVVM priciple, so you might not want to use it if your project has a very restricted ruleset in regard of MVVM.