# In WPF, how to create a custom window that edges don't exceed screen edge when the window is maximized, and has smooth animation?

Tags: wpf, windows

When I made a WPF custom window, I encountered this problem.

My goal is to have a window with rounded corners, window animation, and edges that do not exceed the screen.

I found lots of solution on Internet to solve these problem. as below

---

### 1. rounded corners

I found this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners

and I encapsulate the solution on this site into a class.

```cs
public static class WindowCornerRestorer
{
    // The enum flag for DwmSetWindowAttribute's second parameter, which tells the function what attribute to set.
    // Copied from dwmapi.h
    public enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE
    {
        DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE = 33
    }

    // The DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE enum for DwmSetWindowAttribute's third parameter, which tells the function
    // what value of the enum to set.
    // Copied from dwmapi.h
    public enum DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE
    {
        DWMWCP_DEFAULT = 0,
        DWMWCP_DONOTROUND = 1,
        DWMWCP_ROUND = 2,
        DWMWCP_ROUNDSMALL = 3
    }

    // Import dwmapi.dll and define DwmSetWindowAttribute in C# corresponding to the native function.
    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
    internal static extern void DwmSetWindowAttribute(
        IntPtr hwnd,
        DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE attribute,
        ref DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE pvAttribute,
        uint cbAttribute
    );

    public static void ApplyRoundCorner(Window window)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle();
        var attribute = DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE;
        var preference = DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE.DWMWCP_ROUND;
        DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, attribute, ref preference, sizeof(uint));
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```cs
WindowCornerRestorer.ApplyRoundCorner(this); // this is a Window
```

it works

---

### 2. window animation

I found solution on : [How to restore the default show/close animations for a window when setting WindowStyle in WindowLoaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175722/how-to-restore-the-default-show-close-animations-for-a-window-when-setting-windo)

and as above.

```cs
public static class WindowAnimRestorer
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

    public const int GWL_STYLE = -16;

    public static class WS
    {
        public static readonly long
        WS_BORDER = 0x00800000L,
        WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000L,
        WS_CHILD = 0x40000000L,
        WS_CHILDWINDOW = 0x40000000L,
        WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x02000000L,
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS = 0x04000000L,
        WS_DISABLED = 0x08000000L,
        WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000L,
        WS_GROUP = 0x00020000L,
        WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000L,
        WS_ICONIC = 0x20000000L,
        WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x01000000L,
        WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000L,
        WS_MINIMIZE = 0x20000000L,
        WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000L,
        WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000L,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
        WS_POPUP = 0x80000000L,
        WS_POPUPWINDOW = WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU,
        WS_SIZEBOX = 0x00040000L,
        WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000L,
        WS_TABSTOP = 0x00010000L,
        WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000L,
        WS_TILED = 0x00000000L,
        WS_TILEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
        WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000L,
        WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000L;
    }

    public static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        {
            return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
        }
        else
        {
            return new IntPtr(SetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong.ToInt32()));
        }
    }

    public static void AddAnimTo(Window window)
    {
        var myHWND = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        IntPtr myStyle = new(WS.WS_CAPTION | WS.WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS.WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS.WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS.WS_SYSMENU | WS.WS_SIZEBOX);
        SetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(null, myHWND), GWL_STYLE, myStyle);
    }
}
```

and I use it:

```cs
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WindowAnimRestorer.AddAnimTo(this); // this is a Window
}
```

---

### 3. window edge issues

I find solution on https://github.com/angelsix/fasetto-word/blob/dc1d288472211d8d0e7b7baf580e51dfb6552b6f/Source/Fasetto.Word/Window/WindowResizer.cs

and [Properly maximizing WPF window with WindowStyle=None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941443/properly-maximizing-wpf-window-with-windowstyle-none)

and same:

```cs
public class WindowResizer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// use in Window.SourceInitialized()
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="window"></param>
    public static void CoverResizeIssue(Window window)
    {
        var mWindowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(mWindowHandle).AddHook(WindowProc);
    }

    private static IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case 0x0024:
                WmGetMinMaxInfo(hwnd, lParam);
                break;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }


    private static void WmGetMinMaxInfo(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        POINT lMousePosition;
        GetCursorPos(out lMousePosition);

        IntPtr lCurrentScreen = MonitorFromPoint(lMousePosition, MonitorOptions.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
        
        MINMAXINFO lMmi = (MINMAXINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MINMAXINFO));

        MONITORINFO lCurrentScreenInfo = new MONITORINFO();

        if (GetMonitorInfo(lCurrentScreen, lCurrentScreenInfo) == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Position relative pour notre fenêtre
        lMmi.ptMaxPosition.X = lCurrentScreenInfo.rcWork.Left - lCurrentScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Left;
        lMmi.ptMaxPosition.Y = lCurrentScreenInfo.rcWork.Top - lCurrentScreenInfo.rcMonitor.Top;
        lMmi.ptMaxSize.X = lCurrentScreenInfo.rcWork.Right - lCurrentScreenInfo.rcWork.Left;
        lMmi.ptMaxSize.Y = lCurrentScreenInfo.rcWork.Bottom - lCurrentScreenInfo.rcWork.Top;

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(lMmi, lParam, true);
    }
    

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);


    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr MonitorFromPoint(POINT pt, MonitorOptions dwFlags);

    enum MonitorOptions : uint
    {
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL = 0x00000000,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 0x00000001,
        MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, MONITORINFO lpmi);


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MINMAXINFO
    {
        public POINT ptReserved;
        public POINT ptMaxSize;
        public POINT ptMaxPosition;
        public POINT ptMinTrackSize;
        public POINT ptMaxTrackSize;
    };


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public class MONITORINFO
    {
        public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MONITORINFO));
        public RECT rcMonitor = new RECT();
        public RECT rcWork = new RECT();
        public int dwFlags = 0;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;

        public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            Left = left;
            Top = top;
            Right = right;
            Bottom = bottom;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it:

```cs
 void Window_SourceInitialized(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowResizer.CoverResizeIssue(this); // this is a Window
}
```

---

### My Problem

The above three solutions can all solve the corresponding problems well when used alone. But the problem arises that there will be conflicts if used together.

I found the animation will disappear when I try to recover the edges issue.

I think there are coverage conflicts may arise between their interfaces.

I am a newbie in window development and I don’t know much about their underlying interfaces. I hope someone can help me answer this question.